# Is there any way to remove notification/status bar, but not in onCreate?

Tags: android, android-activity, statusbar, android-notification-bar

As far as I know, it is possible to hide the notification/title bar, once the
activity is visible (has content) , But... maybe I'm wrong?

Is there any way to hide it after the activity is visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the activity to use a theme that eliminates the notification/title bar. For instance, you can add this as an attribute to your `<activity ... >` tag in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

The presence of a title cannot be changed once you have called `setContentView()`. The only way to hide the title bar after your activity has started is to restart the activity with a modified intent. Do something like this:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
intent.putExtra("NoTitle", true);
finish();

overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in `onCreate()` test whether the "NoTitle" extra is present in the intent and make the appropriate call to `requestWindowFeature()` before calling `setContentView()`.

Comment: I know, this isn't what I want. I don't want to hide it at all, but in some point during the activity running.